# AEM Design Importer - File Not Found

Tags: aem

I'm having a problem with AEM's design importer and wondering if anyone else has seen this or has any suggestions..

After uploading my zip file with the following file structure the page is unable to find my JavaScript file or Fonts. It does however, render my CSS and images and html:

```
- index.html
- css\style.css
- css\bootstrap.css
- css\fonts\*various font files*
- scripts\customjavascript.js
- img\*various img files*
```

The error message in the console says

```
"headindex.htmlclientlibs.min.js does not exist or cannot be found".
```

The file path its looking to find this file is `https://*aemserver*/etc/designs/default/canvas/*domain*/_jcr_content/importer/headindex.htmlclientlibs.min.js`

When I look at CRXDe I can see that my js and font folder/files were successfully imported under etc/designs/default/canvas/importer/ with the following folder structure:

```
css/font/*font files*
headindex.htmlclientlibs/css/style.css
headindex.htmlclientlibs/scripts/customjavascript.js
```

A workaound I have found that works is as follows:
- copying the fonts folder and pasting it under the root of /importer
- copying the customjavascript.js file and pasting it under the root of /importer and also renaming it to headindex.htmlclientlibs.min.js

But our authors don't have access to make these changes so it would kind of defeat the purpose of implementing the importer page to begin with...

I've searched all over and have yet to find anyone else who's had a similar situation or anything in the AEM documentation that addresses this. Hoping this may lead to something as I'm at a bit of a dead end. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have js.txt and css.txt files in your `/etc/designs/default/canvas/*domain*/_jcr_content/importer/headindex.htmlclientlibs`? It might be something with design importer workflow

Comment: Yes, there is a css.txt and js.txt under the headindex.htmlclientlibs folder. The js.txt has two lines pointing to my customjavascript.js file and a pageheadscripts.js file both file paths are correct. I agree it seems to be a problem with the importer workflow, do you if that workflow is documented anywhere?

Comment: Did you find a solution?